# Linux Script to start webiopi service

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, webiopi

```
LOG_FILE=/var/log/webiopi
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/webiopi/config

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="WebIOPi"
NAME=webiopi
HOME=/usr/share/webiopi/htdocs
DAEMON=/usr/bin/python
DAEMON_ARGS="-m webiopi -l $LOG_FILE -c $CONFIG_FILE"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0
```

1)The -x "$DAEMON" only check if python has been installed but it didn't check for the package webiopi, doesn't it?

2)Does Python -m would run the whole package, not just the individual module?

```
# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME
```

3)How does the configuration file /etc/webiopi/config values go into /etc/default/webiopi?From above, I didn't see the command to do that.

```
#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chdir $HOME --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
```

4) above start the python process only but not webiopi?  What's point of python test?It didn't specify is it return 0?

```
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chdir $HOME --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --background --make-pidfile -- \
        $DAEMON_ARGS \
        || return 2
```

5)   Above start webiopi by starting python -m webiopi ***  in the background?

Comment: `DAEMON=/usr/bin/python` is an exceptionally backward way of doing this.  The `DAEMON` file should be your actual script, not the interpreter you use to run it.  If you don't have one then create a one-liner with the command you run, and install it somewhere like `/usr/bin/webiopi`.  Maybe add some sanity checks for verifying that the Python library is installed, too.

Comment: @triplee, so on question 1, it doesn't check for package webiopi then?

Comment: That is correct; the code you have right now does not check for the package.  But it will fail which is probably a good enough indication that it is not available, just not very user-friendly.